# SSIS - How can you use a flat file of ID's in a Where statement?

Tags: sql, foreach, ssis, flat-file

I have a large (25,000) list of ID values that, at times, I'd like to just script a query to use instead of running against the full data set (100's of millions or rows) and the hard limit of 8,000 characters in the OLE DC Source SQL Command Text field won't allow them all.  The client's server is locked up and I can't run BULK INSERT and can only use Temp Tables.

It would be something like this:

```
Select ID, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, ...
From TableX
Where ID in (list of ID's from flat file)
```

I was hoping there would be some way to refer to a flat file with all the ID's in it either in the WHERE clause or via somekind of ForEach Loop.  I've setup other ForEach loops but am unsure of A) IF it can even be done and B) how to go about it.

I've poked around the web but not getting any direct hits.  Any direction to go and research would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Load them into a table. Then, a simple join will do the trick.

Comment: I think what you want to do is run each source (table and file flat) through sorts and then into a Merge Join.  From the Merge Join, you can do a Conditional Split and route the records where the key column from the file file is not null to your desired destination.  This I think is effectively a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Duston  Interesting.  If I run the main data table query though it'll still run through the 100's of millions of rows, yes?  Trying to avoid that.  Is there some way to effect & limit the main table query before it hits all those records?  I know I can setup a ForEach loop for each value but then we have to run 25,000 iterations of that loop for it to finish - even if it's pulling on Indexed ID values that's a lot of iterations.  Thoughts ...

Comment: Yes, it'll hit the millions of records.  Your other alternative is what The Impaler suggested.

Comment: Like @TheImpaler said. an inner Join on a table is exactly the same as where in(  ) except more efficient. Index your ID in both tables.